# Evitar hacer click "a través" de un panel en WPF

Tags: wpf, gridview

Estoy usando el control `C1DropDown` dentro de la celda de un `GridView`.

Este control no es más que un botón que al pulsarlo abre un panel con contenido justo debajo del botón (en mi caso el contenido es un Listbox con CheckBoxes).

Este panel, lógicamente sobrepasa los límites de la celda del GridView, flotando por encima de varias filas.

Mi problema es que al hacer clic en el panel abierto, por ejemplo en un Checkbox, se selecciona la fila del GridView que está por debajo, es decir, el GridView sigue recibiendo los clics.

**¿Cómo podría evitarlo?**

Comment: Buenas Poeta, bienvenido. He editado tu texto para que sea mas legible, y he visto que usaste `<br>` para hacer un salto de linea. En este editor, para un parrafo nuevo hay que hacer doble espacio al final del anterior. Prueba a [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/42520/edit) tu pregunta para que veas como la he dejado. Un saludo!

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que estas en Stack Overflow, el cual a diferencia de sitios como Yahoo Respuestas, no es un sitio donde preguntes algo y esperes ayuda sin siquiera mostrar algo de codigo, algo de esfuerzo, para asi poder ayudarte, muestranos que has hecho, que errores tienes durante el proceso, muestranos el codigo, para asi poder ayudarte efectivamente.